# Type check for getElementById only works with optional chaining, not with type check

Tags: typescript, vue.js, chart.js, optional-chaining

When trying to add a gradient to a line chart, I needed to get it's canvas. Before proceeding with the canvas I added a typecheck, however Vetur remarked that the "Object is possibly 'null'.Vetur(2531)"

```
  mounted() {
    const canv = document.getElementById("line-chart") as HTMLCanvasElement;
    if (canv !== null && canv !== undefined) {
      const gradient = canv
        .getContext("2d")
        .createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, canv.height);
```

After researching I attempted to use the optional chaining operator to type check. This approach works, as no error is reported.

```
  mounted() {
    const canv = document.getElementById("line-chart") as HTMLCanvasElement;
    const gradient = canv
      ?.getContext("2d")
      ?.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, canv.height);
```

I'm confused as to why the first approach doesn't work, since canv is a const, thus can't change. A type check should be enough.

Why is only the optional chaining working in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't with `canv`.  The compiler knows that `canv` itself is not `null`, but if you look at the return type for `canv.getContext("2d")`, *that* is possibly `null`:

```
HTMLCanvasElement.getContext(
  contextId: "2d", 
  options?: CanvasRenderingContext2DSettings | undefined
): CanvasRenderingContext2D | null
```

That is what the "Object is possibly null" error is complaining about. You can fix that with optional chaining after that call, such as:

```
if (canv !== null && canv !== undefined) {
    const gradient = canv.getContext("2d")?.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, canv.height)
}
```

Or you can do a more spelled-out type check:

```
if (canv !== null && canv !== undefined) {
    const context = canv.getContext("2d");
    if (context) {
        const gradient = context.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, canv.height)
    }
}
```

Or anything else that convinces the compiler that `canv.getContext("2d")` will not be `null`:

```
if (canv !== null && canv !== undefined) {
    const gradient = (canv.getContext("2d") || { createLinearGradient: () => undefined })
        .createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, canv.height);
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&ts=4.0.5#code/MYewdgzgLgBMCGYBuMC8MAmJgFcC2ApmFAHQDmBUAogDYGHEBCAngJIYAUARDQJZgEAtMAAW8AE5QuAShjwIMABIAVALIAZAMKIk82vSJQA3AFgAULwBmMDgmQwAhKnRgcNGjABknuDsfOYHDAMAkt+AgxZAG9zGDi4cGgYMnF4DF5DNF9kckpNcCgCAA8obgAmDBkAfhJgcQJ4QvVwiQBxVPTDDgAGABoYPoH+uyQSEQJeMhEoaXMAX1jzKxsR-xc3D29slCd0IJCwgUiYGLN4hMhYUGJi2HQR3Kh8m5LyyulTM-jl2wLb6Ni53i1ySKTSGWIWWuhRKtXqjQIzQEbQ6ENKgwxwx0YwmUxmgLiCzMRKW1lsfl2MFc7i8PlWlP2oXCx1O5xBsDBnUh6HJOQoTz+ry4FRkMAAPmKTnB4U0WuJ2uDDAAuGyyVAAPkCwSZRxgc1mXyBMDhDVlyPlqK6mKG2xxk2mH3mQA)